# Existe algum compilador AoT para Java?

Tags: java, compiladores

Eu já vi o [Excelsior Jet](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/) mas ele é privado e pago. Se existe algum livre, como faço para usa-lo no windows?(Digo isso porque tem muita coisa pra linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe este "https://gcc.gnu.org/java/" porém é muito limitado.

Comment: Obrigado, só achei meio difícil de colocar no windows